# integer traits (is_integer, is_integral)

Tags: c++, traits, type-traits

I need two traits concerning integers.

1. The first one would be like `std::is_integral` (or `boost::is_integral`), but usable with user defined types (for example a class wrapping an `int`, say `int_wrapper`): true if the type behaves like an integer and whose representation is like standard integral types (e.g. `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BITS == std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` if `T` is unsigned) But the definition of an integral type is very rigid, in that it consists of a list of these types. So specializing `std::is_integral` seems difficult, if not forbidden (though not stated explicitly I think): `is_integral` is a "primary" type trait (20.7.4.1, note 3: exactly one primary type trait is true for a type T, in my case `int_wrapper` has already `is_class` equal to true).
   What are the risks I take if I specialize this trait for `int_wrapper`?
   Do you know of a trait class (e.g. in Boost) that fit my needs?
2. The second trait I need is for types having integer semantics (with bits arithmetic operations, bit manipulations etc.). For example the `mpz_class` from GMP would satisfy this trait. Is `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` appropriate for this trait? I read both that it is OK to specialize and set `numeric_limits<T>::is_integer == true` if `T` behaves like an integer, but also (in the C++ standard) that the terms "integral" and "integer" are synonymous (in which case we sould always have `numeric_limits<T>::is_integer == is_integral<T>::value`)

In conclusion, am I better of defining my own traits for my precise needs, or try extending standard ones?

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you want boost and other standard libraries to treat your class as integral. If so, you have no other way but specialize std/boost::is_integral<>. Otherwise make your own is_integral<> with its default implementation forwarding to std/boost::is_integral<> and specialize it for your integral wrapper.